# Ant update version number in file but not in script

Tags: ant

I'm currently working on a script that automatically increments version number. The version is in `major.minor.build` format so I can't use `buildnumber`. I've managed to increment the property in file like this:

```
<propertyfile file="./build.properties">
  <entry key="ver.minor" type="int" operation="+" value="1" pattern="0"/>
</propertyfile>
```

This works but ver.minor is not incremented in script. `<property file="build.properties"/>` also doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer / explanation on Alessandro's blog: http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2010/01/update_your_app_version_using_ant_bui.php
Here's the target:

```
<target name="update-version">
<propertyset id="tdate"></propertyset>
<tstamp>
    <format property="tdate" pattern="yyyyMMdd"/>
</tstamp>
<buildnumber file="build.number"/>
<echo>updating version to current datetime: ${tdate}</echo>
<replaceregexp byline="true">
    <regexp pattern="public static const BUILD_DATE: String = \'([0-9]+)'"/>
    <substitution expression="public static const BUILD_DATE: String = '${tdate}'"/>
    <fileset dir="src/it/sephiroth/somestuff">
        <include name="Library.as"/>
    </fileset>
</replaceregexp>

<replaceregexp byline="true">
    <regexp pattern="public static const BUILD_NUMBER: String = \'([0-9\.]+)'"/>
    <substitution expression="public static const BUILD_NUMBER: String = '${build.number}'"/>
    <fileset dir="src/it/sephiroth/somestuff">
        <include name="Library.as"/>
    </fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```

Alessandro's example is for Actionscript which didn't work too well on my Java, so here's what I used:

```
    <target name="update-version">
    <property file="build_info.properties" />
    <property name="build.number" value="${build.major.number}.${build.minor.number}.${build.revision.number}" />
    <echo>Updating build number: ${build.number}</echo>
    <propertyset id="tdate" />
    <tstamp>
        <!-- 02.10.2011 21:27 -->
        <format property="tdate" pattern="MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm" />
    </tstamp>
    <echo>Updating version to current datetime: ${tdate}</echo>
    <replaceregexp byline="true"
        match="BUILD_DATE = &quot;([0-9\.]+)&quot;" 
        replace="BUILD_DATE = &quot;${tdate}&quot;">
        <fileset dir="src/my/package">
            <include name="Application.java" />
        </fileset>
    </replaceregexp>
    <replaceregexp byline="true"
        match="BUILD_NUMBER = &quot;([0-9\.]+)&quot;" 
        replace="BUILD_NUMBER = &quot;${build.number}&quot;">
        <fileset dir="src/my/package">
            <include name="Application.java" />
        </fileset>
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

The only catch is that you have to have a properties file named "build_info.properties" with the three properties in it.

```
build.major.number=01
build.minor.number=00
build.revision.number=0001
```